# Behavioral Sigma-Delta simulation error

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I am trying to simulate a behavioral sigma delta modulator as shown in the circuit below. Basically, I am trying to sense the current through I1 by measuring the ratio of the number of times the voltage across the capacitor dips below some value relative to the number of measurements (number of clock cycles).

[image]

Here's the netlist for convenience.

```
C1 cap 0 10p
B1 comp 0 V=V(clk) > 0.5 ? (V(cap) < 5 ? 1 : 0) : 0
I1 cap 0 10µ
B2 vdd cap I=V(comp) > 0.5 ? 50u : 0
V1 vdd 0 1
V2 clk 0 PULSE(0 1 5n 100p 100p 5n 10n)
R1 cap 0 10Meg
.IC V(cap)=5
.tran 100n
```

Simulating the above circuit produces the following error with LtSpice. Any idea how it can be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding GMIN across current sources solves your "time-step-too-small" problem.

Tools=>Control Panel=>Hacks!=>Set "Add GMIN across current sources" option.